# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest Only Redirect the last URL

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am building an extension that redirect to google.com if the URL is in a black list.
I store the black list in a file "list.txt" locally and use XMLHttpRequest to retrieve the list of URL.
The problem I am having is that the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest only redirect if the URL is the last one in the list.
Here is my code:

```
var list = ["something.something/something"];

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        list = xhr.responseText.split(/\n/);
        abc();
    }
}

xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('text/list.txt'), true);
xhr.send(null);

function abc() {
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function (details) {
            return {redirectUrl: "https://google.com"};
        },
        {urls: list, types: []},
        ["blocking"]);
}
```

File "list.txt" is:

```
*://*.domain1.com/*
*://*.domain2.com/*
*://*.domain3.com/*
*://*.domain4.com/*
```

Is only redirect if the URL is domain4.com.

Please help.

Note that I declare

```
var list = ["something.something/something"];
```

Because chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest will redirect every URL if the list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are using windows to save the .txt file, which terminates line with `\r\n`. So all except the last url ends with a `\r` that won't match the url. I suggest:

```
list = xhr.responseText.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Comment: That, or `.split(/\r?\n/)`

Comment: \r\n seems to be the problem. I change the format of .txt file to *://*.domain1.com/*;*://*.domain2.com/*;*://*.domain3.com/* and list = xhr.responseText.split(";"); and it works, Thank you a lot.